# How to make all links in blocks open in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, hyperlink

I am seeking a way to make all links on a page to open in a new tab. But this should only apply to links within blocks.

Here's the snippet that's supposed to find all blocks on a page.

```
jQuery.fn.PageBlocks = function() {
$("*").filter(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var tagName = $this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
    return $this.css("display") == 'block' || tagName == 'div';
});
}
```

Now I want to use this code in a function that should modify the `target` attribute for the links.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var res = $(document).PageBlocks();
    $.each(res, function(index, val) {
          val.querySelectorAll('a').attr("target", "_blank");
    });
});
```

It looks like I am doig it all wrong. How do I make it properly?
Thank you.

Comment: What is a _"block"_? Why `jQuery.fn.PageBlocks`? `.attr()` is a method of jQuery and not of [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) (the return value of [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: _"Any div wtih cutom class name"_ - Why don't you use this custom class instead of fetching every element in the DOM? -> `$(".myBlockElement:visibile")`

Comment: I would still go with `$("div:visible a").attr("target", "_blank")`

Comment: please provide the html

Comment: @tuhin47 , here's the layout.
```<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
 <head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
  <title>HTML5</title> 
  <!--[if IE]> 
   <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
  <![endif]--> 
 </head><body><div class="MyBlock"><a href="http:\\goo.me">Link</a><br>
</div><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script>$(document).ready(funct...
</script></body></html>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is now working. In your code `jQuery.fn.PageBlocks` is not working and `$(document).PageBlocks()` return undefine. Working [link](https://jsfiddle.net/qxy2oe57/1/)

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>HTML5</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="MyBlock"><a href="http:\\goo.me">Link</a><br> </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var res = $("*").filter(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var tagName = $this.prop("tagName").toLowerCase();
      return $this.css("display") == 'block' && tagName == 'div';
    });
    // console.log(res);

    $.each(res, function(index, val) {
      $(val).find('a').attr("target", "_blank");
    });
  })
</script>
```

Comment: It is because in filter you set the `return $this.css("display") == 'block' || tagName == 'div';`. it should be `return $this.css("display") == 'block' && tagName == 'div';`

Comment: your PageBlocks() doesn't work cause you don't set any return type for this function. So every time it is returned undefine. you should return the filtered value.

Comment: already mentioned. It is because in filter setted the `return $this.css("display") == 'block' || tagName == 'div';`. it should be `return $this.css("display") == 'block' && tagName == 'div';` so. there should be and condition not or according to your choice.

Comment: is it work now? Then don't forget to mark it right if it is right :)

Comment: Thank you, once again! Could you please fix the issue with PageBlocks' return value type? So that I knew what was the error there. What would be the proper declaration?

Comment: Ah, so the main issue was the operator that did match only part of the code! Heck. Thank you. I leared something thanks to your help.

Answer (score 1):

`.attr()` is a method of jQuery, not of NodeList:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   var res = $(document).PageBlocks();
   $.each(res, function(index, val) {
      $(val).find('a').attr("target", "_blank");
   });
})
```

Comment: Yes i was missing a jQuery selector, i edited the answer

Comment: still didn't work for me. Could be the PageBlocks() plugin didn't work? At least ```<div class="myClass"> 
    <a href="http:\\goo.me">Link</a><br>
</div>``` didn't get the 'target' attribute. Any clues? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that can help!!

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class='classBlock'>
<a id='a1' href='https://www.w3schools.com'>click me open</a><br />
<a id='a2' href='https://www.w3schools.com'>click me open</a><br />
<a id='a3' href='https://www.w3schools.com'>click me open</a><br />
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.classBlock').find('a').prop('target', '_blank');
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Keep me posted for any help...

Comment: Thanks, @Niks. That code is cool, but it targets only a specific class. I've had this ```$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
    $(this).find('a').attr("target", "_blank"); 
  });
});``` before. I want this to work on any 'div' and on **block** **elemements** too, so that I don't have to specify class names or IDs.